# Chrome extension to get the most recent resource of a particular type

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension which would perform the equivalent of:

- Opening the Developer tools in Chrome
- Search for the most recent resource of a particular Type (on Network tab)
- Select the Request URL of that resource
- Modify that URL and then display it to the user

I've done some very basic extensions before, but don't know where to start with this one.

How do I locate the Request URL?
If anyone has an example (simply getting any data that the Developer tools contain and displaying it in the popup maybe?) it would be really useful!

Thank you so much!

Hopefully one day I'll be able to return the favour for future programmers :)

Lloyd

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools

Comment: ex: `performance.getEntries("script").pop()`